# Problem in NumPy array while appending values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

arr3 = np.array([], dtype=float)
val=1
for i in range(7):
    if i == 0 or i == 3:
        np.append(arr3,np.nan)
    else:       
        np.append(arr3,val)
        val+=1
arr3
```

**Output**

```
array([], dtype=float64)
```

When I run this code it does not provide any output. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Why didn't you use list append?  `np.append` is a poor imitation of something works better.

Comment: i created the array using numpy package so i thought that i should use one of those functions provided in numpy for managing the array.

Comment: Iterative stuff is usually faster with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as [numpy.append docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) says *append does not occur in-place*, that is `numpy.append` `return`s new array. Consider following example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0],dtype='uint8')
arr2 = np.append(arr,1)
print(arr) #[0]
print(arr2) #[0 1]
```

Your code should work after altering following lines:

```
np.append(arr3,np.nan)
```

to

```
arr3=np.append(arr3,np.nan)
```

and

```
np.append(arr3,val)
```

to

```
arr3=np.append(arr3,val)
```

Answer (score 0):

List append is faster than `np.append` (or any of the other variations on `np.concatenate`).  List append works in-place, adding a 'pointer' to the existing list.  `np.concatenate` (even with the `np.append` cover) creates a new array each call, requiring a full copy.  If you must build an array iteratively, use lists:

```
In [85]: alist = []                                                                  
In [86]: val=1                                                                       
In [87]: for i in range(7): 
    ...:     if i==0 or i==3: 
    ...:         alist.append(np.nan) 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         alist.append(val) 
    ...:         val +=1 
    ...:                                                                             
In [88]: alist                                                                       
Out[88]: [nan, 1, 2, nan, 3, 4, 5]
In [89]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                       
In [90]: arr                                                                         
Out[90]: array([nan,  1.,  2., nan,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```